# Does registering many classes with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE have negative effects?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

We are auto-generating code for a significant number (1000+) of small classes.

As we will use some of those classes in QVariants and/or signals we are considering whether to include the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro in the generated code for all those classes. Possible alternatives we have considered would be to only generate the macro only for the classes that require it or adding the macro as required in non-auto-generated code.

```
//Foo.h
class Foo {
    public:
        //...
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Foo)
```

One concern has been what the (negative) impact  of adding thousands of classes via `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` (e.g. for performance, memory use, compile time, etc.) would be. I've been [investigating](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-1), but haven't found anything relevant so far - does anyone have relevant experience/insights in that regard?

Comment: You should investigate the impact caused by adding thousands of template class specialization to your code, because `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` expands to `template <>  struct QMetaTypeId< TYPE > {...};`. Definitely it will increase the size of your binaries, for example.

Comment: Note that in those instances where the auto-generated code is unused it might be possible to remove it using link-time optimization (assuming your tool chain supports it).

Comment: @vahancho I'll try that, but I had been hope that someone already had already had some experience in that regard (including things that you might miss like "Oh, don't do that, after 5894 registered meta-objects the oldest registered meta-object will be overwritten" etc.)

Comment: @G.M. We use LTCG so unused templates and functions might bloat our .obj and .lib files but the executables should be lean and trim :)